# file.js.coffee.erb not updating

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have some Javascript (initially CoffeeScript) code that uses data from the database. I create the data array with .erb, then do the code with .coffee, and finally use the .js. Fairly standard stuff. The problem is that the javascript served to the browser is cached and never refreshes, even after a server restart or assets:clean.

To get the javascript to refresh I have to delete the tmp folder contents and start the server.

Q1. How can I make the javascript refresh on every request? I tried to inline the code using Coffeebeans to render a file with the code but the code appears html encoded.

Q2. Will this even work on Heroku? (it only accepts precompiled assets)

Comment: are you serving that in an answer ? A bit of code maybe ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "are you serving that in an answer". As for code, on the .js.coffee.erb put something like: alert '<%= Customer.first.name %>'

Comment: You serve that as a view, right ?

Comment: I've tried to include the js file (javascript_include_tag) and also include the script inline in the view (using render to point to a file with the code). Haven't found a way to make either work. The first one has the problem described in the question (it doesn't refresh). The second one doesn't work at all (if I try to render .js.coffee.erb it complains it doesn't have a handler, if I try to render a .html.erb inside a coffeebeans tag the code is html encoded)